# Export/import/dump mongodb - make a copy of the database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an instance (`instance a`) running with mongo db. I setup another instance (`instance b`), and I would like to do a copy of instance a mongo database into instance b - these instances are not related in any way.

I am new to mongo, therefore reading online gave me many options - i noticed i can do mongodump, export, backup, restore etc.

Whats the best solution in my case, and what is the best way to do it?

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your first instance listens on port 27017 and your second one listens on port 12345,

You go (in command propt):

```
mongodump --port 27017

mongorestore --port 12345
```

There are other command line options that you may want to know about dumping (which are not a part of your question). You can read about them in this excellent article: [Backup and restore tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)

**Edit:**

As you mentioned in your comment, your two MongoDB instances are located on two different servers. In that case, you also need to use the --host option. And you also might need the --username and --password options. For example, in case you use port 27017 in both servers, you go:

```
mongodump
```

and then:

```
mongorestore --host <the other server ip>
```

or in case that you need credentials:

```
mongorestore --host <the other server ip> --username <your username> --password <your password>
```

Plesae the documentation I've attached above. It's really short and to the point and will give you all the information you need.

Comment: But like I said these are totally separate ec2 instances, so I do not see this working as there is no way the two instances communicate

Comment: @emisqwe Oh I was thinking you meant two instances of MongoDB on the same machine. In case of two servers, you need to use --host. I've updated my answer.